# Getting Directory Not Found When Not Looking For That Directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to display random image from an array that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "weedle",
        "image": "https://c0.klipartz.com/pngpicture/478/959/sticker-png-pokemon-red-and-blue-pokemon-x-and-y-weedle-beedrill-others-tail-pokemon-evolution-pokemon-red-and-blue-pokemon-x-and-y.png"
    },
    {
        "name": "caterpie",
        "image": "https://img.favpng.com/2/19/21/pok-mon-diamond-and-pearl-pok-mon-sun-and-moon-pok-mon-tcg-online-caterpie-png-favpng-znPm71z43VHMdHAMhCqitLD5w_t.jpg"
    }
]
```

This is the line that should store one of them randomly. I'm not even sure if what I'm trying to do is possible:

```
const pokemon = require('./pokemon.json');
const pokemonImage = new Discord.MessageAttachment(pokemon[0].image[Math.floor(Math.random() * pokemon.length)]);
```

When attempting this and trying to have the message sent, I got this error:

```
(node:8880) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\xaguy\Desktop\PokeCord (My Version)\DiscordBot\h'
```

I'm not sure why it's trying to search for the directory "h" when I'm not searching for it in the first place.

If I remove "image" in "pokemon[0].image" I get this error:

```
(node:1520) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined
    at findName (C:\Users\xaguy\Desktop\PokeCord (My Version)\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\APIMessage.js:290:17)
    at Function.resolveFile (C:\Users\xaguy\Desktop\PokeCord (My Version)\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\APIMessage.js:306:31)
    at C:\Users\xaguy\Desktop\PokeCord (My Version)\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\APIMessage.js:241:72
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at APIMessage.resolveFiles (C:\Users\xaguy\Desktop\PokeCord (My Version)\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\APIMessage.js:241:46)
    at TextChannel.send (C:\Users\xaguy\Desktop\PokeCord (My Version)\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\interfaces\TextBasedChannel.js:172:46)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\xaguy\Desktop\PokeCord (My Version)\DiscordBot\index.js:33:50)
    at Client.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\xaguy\Desktop\PokeCord (My Version)\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\xaguy\Desktop\PokeCord (My Version)\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
```

Comment: Also one of my friends that is helping me maintain my other bot is getting the second error when attempting to display an image. When I did it, it worked fine, when he used the same code, he got "path undefined". I'm assuming the issue has to do with that mainly. To add, I sent him all the files for the bot. I also copied and pasted the files in a new folder to start up as a new bot. I've done that before with no issues up until now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's dig down into what is going on in here:

```
const pokemonImage = new Discord.MessageAttachment(pokemon[0].image[Math.floor(Math.random() * pokemon.length)]);
```

You start with this array in `pokemon`:

```
[
    {
        "name": "weedle",
        "image": "https://c0.klipartz.com/pngpicture/478/959/sticker-png-pokemon-red-and-blue-pokemon-x-and-y-weedle-beedrill-others-tail-pokemon-evolution-pokemon-red-and-blue-pokemon-x-and-y.png"
    },
    {
        "name": "caterpie",
        "image": "https://img.favpng.com/2/19/21/pok-mon-diamond-and-pearl-pok-mon-sun-and-moon-pok-mon-tcg-online-caterpie-png-favpng-znPm71z43VHMdHAMhCqitLD5w_t.jpg"
    }
]
```

You get the first element via `pokemon[0]`:

```
{
        "name": "weedle",
        "image": "https://c0.klipartz.com/pngpicture/478/959/sticker-png-pokemon-red-and-blue-pokemon-x-and-y-weedle-beedrill-others-tail-pokemon-evolution-pokemon-red-and-blue-pokemon-x-and-y.png"
    }
```

Then the `image` property:

```
"https://c0.klipartz.com/pngpicture/478/959/sticker-png-pokemon-red-and-blue-pokemon-x-and-y-weedle-beedrill-others-tail-pokemon-evolution-pokemon-red-and-blue-pokemon-x-and-y.png"
```

Then you use `[Math.floor(Math.random() * pokemon.length)]` to get the character at a random index in that string, heavily biased to the front based on the length of the pokemon array. In the posted error, that random character was `h`. The discord library tries to resolve `h` to a file relative to the working directory and of course fails.

I presume you want to pick a random pokemon and then get the image, which would be something more like this.

```
const pokemonImage = new Discord.MessageAttachment(pokemon[Math.floor(Math.random() * pokemon.length)].image)
```

Comment: Wow that was a perfect breakdown. Had I done that myself I would’ve realized immediately. Thank you for that. Now it may just be bad luck since it’s 50/50 but it only seems to be displaying the second image. I’ve tested it 13 times and each time it was caterpie that showed up. Is that just bad luck or is something else wrong?

Comment: @QuazArxx I tested the random number generation and get each number within a few hundred times of the other running 100k at a time, that seems like a coincidence. https://jsfiddle.net/tnmuw710/1/

Comment: Gotcha thank you for your help. Do you know why I was also getting path undefined? Maybe the reasoning can help me fix why my friends’ code won’t work when I told him what to type out.

Comment: @QuazArxx That is worth a separate question.